# The videojs skin vim is not overriding the original styles.

Tags: javascript, css, html

So I'm using the VideoJS plug on this site that I'm building. I'm implimenting here like this:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/video-js.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="Video JS" charset="utf-8">

<style>
    @import url(css/vim.css);
</style>

</head>
```

And vim doesn't seem to override the video-js.css calls. I've tried this with other skins and the same result happens. I attempted to change the placement in reverse, but that did not suffice. Please let me know if there is something that I could be missing.

Answer (score 1):

I think `@import` rules usually need to come before other rules, or they'll be ignored in some browsers. Why can't you just link to the second stylesheet as you do the first? Do you need to import for certain media?

Comment: I attempted that, but still had issues with it at first. Should I just attempt to override it with the vim.css with the CSS calls some place else?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, folks. I forgot to add the function at the top of the page to enable this.